# listview with switch and on checked change listener issue

Tags: android, listview, event-handling

In my alarm app:
Main activity contains a list-view having text views and switch buttons, i have applied on checked change listener. Whenever i switch one alarm ON or OFF it displays a message "Alarm is turned ON" or "Alarm is turned OFF". But when i scroll down and then scroll up the same message appear again. If i continue scrolling down and then up it displays the message again and again. It seems that the code in on checked change listener is executed again and again while scrolling. Please tell me how can i solve this issue. I don't want to execute code in on checked change listener again and again while scrolling.

Comment: post your getView method of your adapter.

Comment: While you want to change it, when your switch state changes?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `checked change listener`. try getting `onclicklistener` of the switch and put the check like this

```
yourswitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        yourswitch.setChecked(!yourswitch.getChecked());
        // update your data model if needed.
    }
});
```

your are facing this issue because when you scroll the list when a perticular view comes into memory it try to check or uncheck your switch on basis of your datamodel as a result `checkedChange listener` get called again and again.

**For SwitchDrag case.**

```
  view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
        {
          switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    yourswitch.setChecked(!yourswitch.getChecked());
                   // update your data model if needed.
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Try implementing `onTouchLisrtener`. I believe `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` will get called when user drag the switch and take his finger up.

Comment: yes, i used the on click listener but onClick does not trigger when user drags the switch thumb. How can i do that?

Comment: when i apply on touch listener switch can not be dragged.

Comment: are u using some custome class for your switch view.?

Comment: I am using android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat

Comment: I found the solution. I used onCheckedChangeListener and in onCheckedChanged() method i used if(buttonView.isShown()) and placed the code in the if condition. Now code is not executed automatically.